# message : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I face problem at next code :

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

mysql code :

```
SELECT classes.id,
    concat(classes.grade_name+"/"+classes.section_name+"/"+classes.class_order) AS classname,

(SELECT sum(points)
FROM studentspoints
WHERE points_type = 1
    AND studentspoints.grade_order = classes.grade_order
    AND studentspoints.class_order = classes.class_order) AS p1,

(SELECT sum(points)
FROM studentspoints
WHERE points_type = 2
    AND studentspoints.grade_order = classes.grade_order
    AND studentspoints.class_order = classes.class_order) AS p2
FROM classes
GROUP by(grade_order,class_order)
```

Comment: `+classes.section_name+` you wanting to do math here? I doubt it; use dots and the same for the others.

Comment: This is mysql, I think it's commas instead of dots.

Comment: @aynber *Aye*, you're on to something ;-)

Comment: I put comma but the problem still

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the MySQL 'concat' function like

```
CONCAT(classes.grade_name, "/", classes.section_name, "/", classes.class_order) as classname
```

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Also you can simply use CONCAT_WS like this:

```
CONCAT_WS("/", classes.grade_name, classes.section_name)
```

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Comment: I change concat .. and replace plus tag to comma but the problem still .